# Kendo: How the retrieve the uploaded file details in ie browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

```
    <input name="files"
                       type="file"
                       data-role="upload"
                       data-async="{ saveUrl: 'save', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true, }"
                       data-multiple="false"
                       data-bind="visible: isVisible,
                                  enabled: isEnabled,
                                  events: { select: onSelect }"/>

  select: function (e) {
                debugger;
                var files = e.files;
                if (files.length > 10) {

                    alert("Maximum 10 files can be uploaded at a time.");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
}
```

In ie browser we want to access the size of the uploaded file from object e or by using any method.

Comment: For which IE versions do you need this?

Comment: jost, may i know is it possible to get size of file..??

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the upload event of the widget?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-upload

in the event argument you have:

e.files Array

List of the files that will be uploaded. Each file has:

name
extension - the file extension including the leading dot - ".jpg", ".png", etc.
size - the file size in bytes (null if not available)

Same is valid for the select event as well.

However this will not work in the IE, due to its limitations, and there is no workaround. You need IE10++